# how to fix this issue when handling permission using permission_handler plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart

I handled permission when app started. like this:

```
  final PermissionHandler _permissionHandler = PermissionHandler();

  Future<Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus>> permissions() async {
    Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> result =
        await _permissionHandler.requestPermissions([
          PermissionGroup.storage,
          PermissionGroup.camera,
        ]);
    return result;
  }
```

**I used multi_image_picker official plugin**

this plugin document said enables below permissions, I didn't add these plugin on android manifest. because I need to used `handler_permission` plugin.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

This error is coming when tap button.

> Please enable access to the storage and the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From permission handler's description 
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler#android-and-ios-specific-permissions 
**For this plugin to work you will have to add permission configuration to your AndroidManifest.xml (Android)**

you still need to add these permission to android manifest

Comment: really? what is the purpose of this plugin?